# Dealing with single quotes in an array

Tags: php, arrays, apostrophe

I have built a PHP/MySQL search engine on my website. The PHP/MySQL works perfectly, returning any matches to the user's input.

I then have an array which highlights the returned text in red. It also censors curse words but I'll omit that part of the code as it's not relevant to my question.

Here's the relevant section of my array:

```
$censorarray = array(
"$input"    => "<span class='redtext'>$input</span>",
"$inputucf" => "<span class='redtext'>$inputucf</span>",
"$inputuc"  => "<span class='redtext'>$inputuc</span>",
"$inputucw" => "<span class='redtext'>$inputucw</span>"
);
```

So, the MySQL query (not shown here) searches for and finds any instances of the search string regardless of case (these are defined earlier in my page where $input is converted using strtolower, strtoupper, ucfirst and ucwords) to allow for any possible combination.

The MySQL query returns things such as *why don't*, *can't* and *Derek's* but the array doesn't highlight them. The issue arises when a user searches for a word or phrase containing an apostrophe.

In other words, my search results display perfectly *except* that the matched text isn't highlighted in red when it contains an apostrophe.

What am I doing wrong?

Apostrophes are stored in my MySQL table "as is" (i.e. not converted to `&apos;` or `&#39;`).

Comment: I've tried using htmlentities with ENT_QUOTES but the array still isn't highlighting the returned results. It works PERFECTLY except on apostrophised words and phrases. Thanks for suggesting the answer lay with the question you deemed similar to my own but I really can't make that fit the particular puzzle I'm up against!!

Comment: I don't see why that would happen based on the PHP code shown. Can you also include the resulting HTML copied from the page source?

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me but I managed to solve this in the early hours of the morning. The problem was I was calling the $input string in the array and that string had been escaped to prevent malicious code injection. By duplicating that string BEFORE it was escaped and passing the duplicate to the array, the problem was resolved!